# Joomla installation - access denied 403

Tags: joomla, installation

I can already tell that I'm probably doing something hideously wrong, but I just can't get anything to work or even acknowledge me.

I have a working Joomla 1.5 site on a localhost setup on a lamp stack with Ubuntu (newest everything). I am working on upgrading the site to a newer version. I've followed the steps on the joomla site, which are simple, just extract the zip file on the server, just like I did for 1.5, and then go to the site. I am doing this in a subdirectory I've called upgrade, physically located at /var/www/upgrade/ and when i try to go to localhost/upgrade, I get a "FORBIDDEN" 403. I tried localhost/upgrade/administrator, localhost/index.php, localhost/administrator/index.php, and even localhost/installation/index.php and nothing works.
I went into the installation/ dir and made and saved the configuration.php and .htaccess in upgrade/ to no avail and as a last resort I even did a chmod -R 777 * (yeah I know), restarted apache but nothing changes.

Just to see if it was the install, I dl'd Joomla 3.2 and got the exact same result. All the while my 1.5 site is still happily working.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to setup a Virtual host for the new site. You can do this with either a port or a host.

So if you have your Apache conf setup correctly you can add another Virtual host with something along the lines of.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/upgrade
    ServerName upgrade.local
</VirtualHost>
```

You'll also need to add a hosts entry which points to your localhost/IP. Its worth checking out a good guide on setting all this up as theres quite a few steps. The Ubuntu one is pretty good if your on that Distro.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP
Specifically the bit on Virtual Hosts

ServerName means that the server will listen for hosts with that name. So, if you have a host such as upgrade.local pointing to your server then the VirtualHost entry will pick that up and point it to the directory /var/www/upgrade.

In order to point a local host to your server you need to add it to your machines hosts file. To add a new host like upgrade.local (you can call it whatever you want) you edit /etc/hosts and set the IP it points to.

```
127.0.0.1    upgrade.local
```

ServerName is not mandatory but I find it better as its easier to organise your local host sites.

The alternative is to do it by port (which means you can avoid having to change the hosts file). You need to listen for the port in this case.

```
Listen 3000

<VirtualHost *:3000>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/upgrade
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Aha, definitely things I didn't know/do. Great read! I'm not really an admin, just pretending to be one :)
I have created the new upgrade.conf and enabled it, and it shows up in apache2/sitesenabled/ and in it I have 

    DocumentRoot /var/www/upgrade

Along with the default stuff that was in the file. What does Server name do, what's the local part in upgrade.local and is it mandatory?
Also, what do you mean by also need to add a hosts entry?
Thanks again

Comment: Updated with details on the serverName and hosts

Comment: OK, so I've added the server name to the upgrade.conf and made sure it did propagate the changes to the enabledsites file as well, and I added 


    127.0.0.1/upgrade   upgrade.local

to the hosts file. Is that right? Because it's still not working, still getting 403. 
It would appear we're heading in the right direction though, because this is the same error I now get when trying to access the 1.5 site.

Comment: You don't the /upgrade in the hosts file. That part is taken care of by the VirtualHosts setting. So just 127.0.0.1 upgrade.local

Comment: OK, I didn't think that looked right. That didn't seem to help though.

I did figure it out though. I had a 

    <Directory /var/www/[old 1.5 site name/>

Comment: <Directory /var/www/[old 1.5 site name/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
        AllowOverride All
        Require All Granted
    </Directory>

from when I was trying to get the redirecting working in the initial setup.  
I added another one for /var/www/upgrade and Poof, the whole thing starts working, with both sites able to be switched between at will.

Thanks so much for all your help.